# Restrict a process to read "/etc/resolv.conf" file in linux

Tags: c, linux, process, dns, fork

In my process, I am creating a child process and running a binary with execl() API. In parent proces calling waitpid() and waiting for child to exit. This binary opens **"/etc/resolv.conf"** and try to connect DNS IP. If DNS ip is not reachable, the child process block for long time. Due to that parent process timeout. I do not have source code of binary and I do not want to change anything to /etc/resolve.conf as this file is used by other process.

Is there any way, I can remove or restrict access of '/etc/resolve.conf' to my child process.

Comment: Does the parent process have root privileges?

Comment: Do you even know what your child process will do if you prevent it from reading `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, This binary can read file from remote location or local disk. I am only using it for reading local disk file. So it is ok if it will not go to network.

Comment: @Ctx Yes, parent process have root privileges.

Comment: Just put the host the application is looking for in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: SELinux can do this, but it's not easy to set up and requires substantial system modification.

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy to prevent the access to `/etc/resolv.conf`. But you can tell the resolver the *number of attempts* to perform for DNS name resolving through the environment variable `RES_OPTIONS`. Even zero attempts are a valid value there and causes name resolution to fail instantly.

See for example:

```
RES_OPTIONS="attempts:0" telnet www.google.de
telnet: could not resolve www.google.de/telnet: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

This means, in your prgram, you could do

```
...
putenv("RES_OPTIONS=attempts:0");
execl(...);
...
```

This should cause the resolving to fail *instantly* and your process should proceed.

Comment: I am always open to constructive critics, please comment on DV